# Yocto Honister + cargo-native = missing openssl

Tags: rust, yocto, openembedded, libssl

Trying to build recipe [cargo-native](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/190135/) (from openembedded-core layer) in Yocto Honister. Compiler tells me that:
`Failed to find OpenSSL development headers.`, specifically:

```
|   running: "/raid/yocto_projects/honister/147/mk_grey/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/cargo-native/1.54.0-r0/wrapper/build-rust-cc" "-O3" "-
ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-isystem/raid/yocto_projects/honister/147/mk_grey/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/cargo-
native/1.54.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include" "-O2" "-pipe" "-I" "/raid/yocto_projects/honister/147/mk_grey/tmp/work/x86_64-li
nux/cargo-native/1.54.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../../usr/include" "-E" "build/expando.c"
|   cargo:warning=build/expando.c:4:24: error: pasting "RUST_VERSION_OPENSSL_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
|   cargo:warning=    4 | #define VERSION2(n, v) RUST_VERSION_##n##_##v
|   cargo:warning=      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
|   cargo:warning=build/expando.c:5:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘VERSION2’
|   cargo:warning=    5 | #define VERSION(n, v) VERSION2(n, v)
|   cargo:warning=      |                       ^~~~~~~~
|   cargo:warning=build/expando.c:10:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘VERSION’
|   cargo:warning=   10 | VERSION(OPENSSL, OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER)
|   cargo:warning=      | ^~~~~~~
|   exit status: 1
|
|   --- stderr
|   thread 'main' panicked at '
|   Header expansion error:
|   Error { kind: ToolExecError, message: "Command \"/raid/yocto_projects/honister/147/mk_grey/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/cargo-native/1.
54.0-r0/wrapper/build-rust-cc\" \"-O3\" \"-ffunction-sections\" \"-fdata-sections\" \"-fPIC\" \"-m64\" \"-isystem/raid/yocto_project
s/honister/147/mk_grey/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/cargo-native/1.54.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include\" \"-O2\" \"-pipe\" \"-I\" \"/
raid/yocto_projects/honister/147/mk_grey/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/cargo-native/1.54.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../
../usr/include\" \"-E\" \"build/expando.c\" with args \"build-rust-cc\" did not execute successfully (status code exit status: 1)."
}
```

I need it to build this example: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/190318/

Any ideas how to ensure OpenSSL development headers are available? I have already bitbaked `openssl` and `openssl-native`, ans also have `libssl-dev` installed on build machine. Building on Ubuntu 20.04. From now on this is a guesswork. Help really appreciated!